# Ionic 4 IonScroll, scroll directive cause button to appear in multiple positions on IOS

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

[image]

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
```

import { DomController } from '@ionic/angular';

```
// TODO deal with position TOP if needed
@Directive({
    selector: '[appScrollHide]'
})
export class ScrollHideDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input('el') el: any;

    //TODO get position from element
    originalPosition = 10;

    constructor(
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        private domCtrl: DomController
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        
        this.domCtrl.write(() => {
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.el, 'transition', 'bottom 100ms');
        });
    }

    @HostListener('ionScroll', ['$event']) onContentScroll($event: any) {

        let detail = $event.detail;

        this.domCtrl.write(() => {
            let position = this.originalPosition - detail.scrollTop;
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.el, 'bottom', `${position}px`);
        });
    }

}
```

I have a scroll directive which hides the button(add vehicle btn) on scroll, its work perfect on Android and web, but on ios i'm getting this weird effect where the button appears in multiple positions in ios only.
Let me know if you have seen this and can help thanks

Answer (score 0):

I met scroll problems with iOS too, not like you, but it looked like this.

Did you try to set this in `app.component.ts` :

```
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot({
      scrollPadding: false,
      scrollAssist: false,
    })
```